# 3d game developer in openGL

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, game-engine

I want to start as a 3d game developer . But I am not getting from where to start.
Should I work on some game engine or should I work to learn openGL which is the core of any game engine.

I am working as an application developer (iPHone) and I have worked on Cocos2d game engine for iPhone.

Any guide lines. Please help.

Comment: OpenGL is not the core of any game engine. Not all game engines use OpenGL. And of those that do OpenGL is definitely not located in the core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to emphasize the "3D" or the "Game" in "3D Game Developer"?

If you emphasize the 3D, you can dig deep into OpenGL, and all the concepts behind 3D graphics, and develop the low level drawing code for your game.  See HG's response for a good start.  3D graphics programming is a huge subject.  Just OpenGL ES, which is available in two incompatible versions under iOS, is a huge subject that could take many months to learn.  Plus if you're writing the rendering code for your game, you'll probably be writing the rest of the game subsystems code such as AI and physics.

If you want to emphasize the Game, you can learn 3D game engines such as cocos3d (as Kazuki Sakamoto mentions).  There are lots of such game engines.  In addition to offering rendering code, these engines may offer other game subsystems.  You'll be working on your game content more than reinventing the game subsystems.

It just depends upon which is more interesting to you.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I should choose what I like to do. But still my emphasize is on 3d , then what ever it takes to learn. I will. Tell me your preference. Should I work on game engines ( Like Unreal, unity3d etc. ) or should I learn core openGL. ?? What do you think would be good.

Comment: Personally I'm more interested in the 3D. Once I got over the learning curve hump, I find that writing shaders in GLSL is fun.

Answer (score 3):

How about [cocos3d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/1274)?

> cocos3d is a significant extension to cocos2d
>   that adds a full 3D modelling space,
>   including 3D mesh models, perspective
>   projection cameras, materials, and
>   lighting.

Comment: The standard comment about libraries like cocos3d applies: to the extent that they simplify things, they do it by abstraction and by facade. You become more limited in what you can do. There's always a point at which adding additional functionality means not just understanding the layer underneath (OpenGL in this case) but the internals of the layer on top as well. So you should ensure that any library you pick does everything you want before you use it, or it becomes a shortcut at the start of the project that adds a massive burden or an artificial limitation later on.

Comment: Hi Tommy, That is what I am asking, I know that cocos2d/cocos3d are both made at the top of openGL . What I see, is if I know opemGL I can customize any open source game engine if needed. But still I am feeling doubt. There are some game engines (newly launched ) like Unreal game engine for iphone . Learning them can also be very adventurous. But still my question is where to start from ? OpenGL or any game engine.